# error param is missing or the value is empty: article in rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails

articles_controller:
I have a little problem on Rails
I have got the error in article_params method.
I've looked at several other solutions to the problem but they do not help me.
Heres my code.

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController


def index
    @articles = Article.all
end

def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @article = Article.new
end

def create
    # render plain: params[:article].inspect
    @article = Article.new (article_params)
    if  @article.save
        redirect_to @article
    else
        render action: 'new'
    end
    
end

def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @article = Article.find (params[:id])
    if @article.update(article_params)
        redirect_to @article
    else
        render action: 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @article.destroy (article_params)
end

private

def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    
end
```

end

index.html.erb:
I wrote button_to helper, but I have got this error

```
    <h3>The articles list</h3>

<% @articles.each do |article|%>
    <h4><%= article.title%></h4>
    <p><%= article.text%></p>
    <p><%=  link_to 'Show', article_path(article)%></p>
    <p><%=  link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article)%></p>
    <p><%= button_to 'Delete',  article_path(article), data: {turbo: false}, method: :delete%></p>
    <hr/>
    <%= params.inspect%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Do not put a space between the name of a method and the parens. Since parens are optional in Ruby you're actually calling `@article = Article.find((params[:id]))` which works when you're just passing a single parameter but which will cause a syntax error if you have multiple parameters or try to pass a keyword argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
@article.destroy (article_params)
```

should just be

```
@article.destroy
```